# How to avoid bloating pages with divs?

Tags: html, css, grid

this is my problem. I used in various project the classical css grids (actually I use 1140px) and now I was thinking to create one for myself.
Some time ago I also talked to a guy that told me to not always use grid for everything otherwise I would have bloated the page with divs. Now, what I don't understand at this point, is how can I not bloat the page with div using any grid. Just a brief example. This is how a menu looks like without using a grid.

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

This is how a menu looks like using a grid system:

```
<div class="column4 prefix4">
<nav>
<div class="column1"><li></li></div>
<div class="column1"><li></li></div>
<div class="column1"><li></li></div>
<div class="column1"><li></li></div>
</nav>
</div>
```

The option would be to not use a grid but it seems to me quite impossible to position elements without grid.
There is surely something that I'm not considering.

Comment: This is HTML. Style it however you want. A `div` isn't anything special. No reason you can't just apply the style you want to the individual `ul`'s and `li`'s. More importantly, what's your specific problem and how have you attempted to solve it?

Comment: I've found that keeping the grid styling on `div`'s helps separate the layout elements from the content elements; I've never been a fan of, say, adding grid stylings onto those li's, in the case that you end up with conflicting styles that will override each other and create styling issues. Also, indentation goes a long way to keep the HTML visually organized.

Comment: Talking about 1140px, for example, the problem was that I couldn't apply classes on individual ul's or li's but only on div's and for every grid, before using column, you had to open another div and apply another class to it.
My final question is: how can avoid all this? If I build my own grid, I will be able to apply every classes to single elements without opening useless div's?

Comment: Keep in mind every HTML element have default CSS, and for each you can "imitate" the behaviour of the other, e.g. a `<div>` can get the same behaviour as a `<ul>`, `<a>`, ... So if you are stuck in using `<div>` instead of other element like regular `<ul>`, try to debug the CSS through your navigator and see which style is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo: http://jsbin.com/buwexe/edit?html,css,output**

If you don't want to clutter the UI with `divs` then you will have to use descriptive classes which are not reusable.

The purpose of a *grid* is to be reusable without being attached to a specific element on the page. For example the below snippet is descriptive and does not clutter the UI but keep in mind, it is not reusable outside of the navigation context.

```
<nav class="navigation">
 <ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
  <li class="nav-item">Contact</li>
  <li class="nav-item">Team</li>
  <li class="nav-item">Work</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
}

.nav:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.nav .nav-item {
  float: left;
  color: #3498db;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  width: 25%;
}

.nav .nav-item:first-of-type {
  border-left: none;
}
```

**Notice how the sizing is done inside the nav-item, this isn't reusable, a grid system would make this more cluttered but more reusable and maintainable which is essential in a team of 2+**